# datasource injection

Tags: datasource, code-injection, java-ee-5

I need help to understand DataSource injection.

- I have defined the jndi datasource in webSphere server and tested the connection within the console return successful.
- When I tried to inject the resource inside a servlet

  `private @Resource(name = "jdbc/order_inquiry") DataSource ds;`
- ds is null when the code tried to get the connection from ds.

  `Connection conn = ds.getConnection();`

My question is do I need to add anything to the web.xml or other configuration file ?